# Machine Culture and DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

We set up a server wit the en-US culture by mistake. Later I changed the regional settings, the locale, and the IIS globalisation to en-GB.

However, I'm having a problem with a Windows service I've written. It's still using the US format whenever DateTime.ToString() is done. I know I can specify the culture I want the string to be in, but I don't want to change all my code. It should just use the UK format because it's changed everywhere in the machine settings.

Maybe there's a setting I've missed? Does anyone have any suggestions apart from changing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the regional settings using Control Panel, you need to check the checkbox "Apply all settings to the current user account **and to the default user profile**".  In XP this is on the Advanced tab of Regional and Language Options.

Your Windows Service is presumably running under an account without a profile (e.g. LocalSystem) so will use the default user profile settings.

You can also inspect the regional settings for the default user profile using RegEdit - they're under the registry key `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International`.

Nevertheless I would consider changing the code - a Windows Service should generally be agnostic about the machine's culture, and you'll be avoiding maintenance headaches down the line.

Comment: Service must be restarted after this change.

Comment: I mentioned that it's a server, so had to go to regional settings -> administrative -> copy.

Answer (score 1):

if your windows service is running on a system account you need to apply the correct (en-GB) language settings [also to reserved accounts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Apply-regional-and-language-settings-to-reserved-accounts)

Comment: Other answer was first, but this is also helpful.

Comment: This link seems to be broken (after 6 years, not surprised)  :(