# DateTime not appearing as per system format c# windows services

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-services, console-application

When we use System.DateTime.Now it displays the DateTime as per what is set in our system (if I am not wrong).
Like currently my system DateTime settings are as below :

[image: My System Date Time Settings]

Now I created a simple Console Application with a small snippet :

```
Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now);          
Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern+" "+System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\perls.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
```

The output both console and text is : 
[image: Console OutPut]

Now same thing I am doing via windows service and Logging some information in a Text File and even creating the same file as created in above sample:
(I have a simple Log class which logs the info i am not getting into its details)
So code is something like below:

```
Log.Info("System Date Time : " + System.DateTime.Now);
Log.Info("Date Time format : " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("E:\\perls-service.txt", System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
```

Now in my Log File (a text file) and the text file which I created gives following output:
[image: Web Service output]

**Both samples are executed in the same system then why is this difference?**
Where am I wrong?
Or this problem is in my system only.

Comment: Where this windows service running? Another server? Maybe it has a different culture settings? How `Log.Info` methods handle `DateTime` values when it's try to write their string representation?

Comment: What happens if you add the following line of code before your second example: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;`

Comment: Probably connected to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474132/windows-service-unable-to-get-correct-system-culture

Comment: Or this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119159/machine-culture-and-datetime

Comment: @SonerGönül  the windows servcie is running in my own system and output also saved in my system(text file). DateTime by Log is written same way as it is writing in file like DateTime time = DateTime.Now; i am not getting into the Log class details coz its a dll which i did not develop but i know its correct coz if I use the log in Console i get -| 2015-02-25 20:54:22 | INFO | 2015-02-25 20:54:22
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss i.e. as per what is set in my system.. i do not think that log has any problems

Comment: @MatthewWatson same output as I have posted already in my question

Answer (score 0):

You must be running into the issue described here 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8fbca78b-5078-4a12-8abb-4051076febbb/c-windows-service-culture-info-problem

Your Windows Service most likely runs under one of the service accounts with the culture defined in the registry.

See if you updating the registry settings below fixes the problem.

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\International]
"Locale"="00000409"
"LocaleName"="en-US"
```